# How do i run a .vbs file from php with parameters

Tags: php, iis, vbscript, outlook, email

I've tried

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$obj = $WshShell->Run("cscript ABSOLUTE/PATH/TO/my_vbs_code.vbs", 0, true);
```

and

```
exec('wscript "C:/path/to/script.vbs"');
```

but neither of them work, i am using the latest PHP using IIS server on windows. My VBScript is used to send an email using Outlook 2015.

To use these functions do i need to edit my php.ini or is there some other way of doing this?

Comment: How exactly this fails? Do you get any message from PHP or in logs? Quite likely it's a permissions problem.

Comment: Also check if safe mode is enabled.